# npm install not working for gzipped tarball

Tags: node.js, gzip, npm, tar

Hi I am trying to install a module globally which i made to a gzipped tarball.I downloaded the source from github and converted to a tar.gz and then i tried to install it using the following command

```
npm install forever.tar.gz -g
```

It threw me the following error

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/administrator/forever.tar.gz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/root/tmp/npm-18157/1367900009061-   0.2676603845320642/package/package.json'
```

My requirement is that i should not connect to any external url (ie) https://registry.npmjs.org/forever for any installation.I should be able to install from the tarball from my directory.I am stuck here any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

this error tells you, that the package.json in your tar was not found...

did you change something in your repository? how did you tarball the repo?

i did these steps and everything worked fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever.git
tar -cvzf forever.tar.gz forever
npm install forever.tar.gz -g
```

hint: you dont need to tarball the repository, npm install can also be performed on local folders:

```
git clone https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever.git
npm install forever/
```

Comment: I did another workaround by just setting the path pointing to the bin folder in the forever module.That worked fine.